# Postgres: How to run command to increment 15 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I use the below command to get data from a timestamp. I want to script something to run the query every 15 minutes (so each time do set the time as 15 minutes onward). What is the syntax for get an incremented 15 minutes?

```
select COUNT(some_field)
  from some_table
 where data_type like 'X' and
       node_type like 'Y' and
       time = '2018-07-02 13:00:00'
```

Comment: So you want to run the query every 15 minutes, and change that WHERE clause that says "and TIME = ..." to be a different value?

Comment: Exactly yes thats it

Comment: For last 15 min?